# Django - setUpTestData & Many to Many relationship

Tags: django, testing

I need to add a many-to-many relationship in my `setUpTestData` sequence so that my tests will run correctly.

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), Many-to-Many relationships cannot be created until an object has been saved, as the primary key must first exist. This means that I cannot set the relationship in `setUpTestData` with `Model.objects.create()` as I do with other variables.

Is there any way to include a Many-to-Many relationship in [setUpTestData](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a partial answer, a solution I found [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) seems to work half way. Here is my code:

(I'm linking a social app to Django's Sites framework so that my tests will be able to run).

**SetupTestData.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp

class TestData(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):

        cls.current_site = Site.objects.get_current()

        cls.SocialApp1 = cls.current_site.socialapp_set.create(
            provider="facebook",
            name="facebook",
            client_id="123456789",
            secret="0987654321",
        )
```

**test_sandbox.py**

```
from MyApp.tests.SetupTestData import TestData
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp

class TestHomePage(TestData):

    def test_sandbox(self):
        print(Site.objects.all())
        print(Site.objects.get_current())
        print(Site.objects.get_current().socialapp_set.all())
        print(self.SocialApp1)
        print(self.SocialApp1.sites)
        print(SocialApp.objects.get(provider='facebook').sites)
```

**Test Output**

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
[<Site: example.com>]
example.com
[<SocialApp: facebook>]
facebook
sites.Site.None
sites.Site.None
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

You can see from the results that I can locate the app via Sites, but it doesn't seem to work backwards. I suppose if I somehow reversed the relationship in `setUpTestData` I could make it work the opposite way instead. I'll leave the question open for a better solution.